# Convert varchar column to inet

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, ddl, default-value

I have a table column containing IP addresses, datatype is `varchar(255)`. I want to switch to `inet` datatype now. Is there a way to convert existing addresses in IP column to `inet` datatype? Tried:

```
ALTER TABLE request_logs ALTER COLUMN ip type inet USING ip::inet;
ALTER TABLE request_logs ALTER COLUMN ip type inet USING CAST(ip AS inet);
```

But no luck, getting:

> ```
> PG::DatatypeMismatch:
> ERROR:  default for column "sign_up_ip" cannot be cast automatically to type inet
> ```

All values are `'127.0.0.1'`. Postgres version is 9.6.9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ALTER TABLE` statement works for me. The error message indicates that the column `sign_up_ip` has a **`DEFAULT`** value attached to it, which is not valid for the new data type `inet`. Drop the default of the column first, then convert the data type. *Then* add a new default (if applicable).

Even if it would *seem* valid. [The manual, chapter "Changing a Column's Data Type":](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-alter.html#id-1.5.4.7.10)

> PostgreSQL will attempt to convert the column's default value (if any)
>   to the new type, as well as any constraints that involve the column.
>   But these conversions might fail, or might produce surprising results.
>   It's often best to drop any constraints on the column before altering
>   its type, and then add back suitably modified constraints afterwards.

There is no cast registered between `varchar` and `inet`. That's why you had to add the `USING` clause with an explicit conversion. Postgres makes it work via input / output conversion. But that's not possible for the saved `DEFAULT` expression.

You can do it all in a single DDL command to minimize friction with concurrent transactions (if that should matter):

```
ALTER TABLE request_logs
   ALTER COLUMN sign_up_ip DROP default
 , ALTER COLUMN sign_up_ip type inet USING ip::inet
 , ALTER COLUMN sign_up_ip SET DEFAULT '192.168.1.1';  -- arbitrary example
```

Using your *actual* column name `sign_up_ip` instead of the symbolic `ip` in your code example. Tested in Postgres 10.

**If** your column should hold any `varchar` values not valid as type `inet`, your conversion still fails, but this time with something like:

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type inet: "1234.123.123.123"
> ```

That's one reason why doing all in a single statement (or at least in a single transaction) is a good idea: Everything is back to the original state after the error and the automatic `ROLLBACK`.